# Imprimir conteúdo de um objeto pertencente a um TreeSet (Collection)

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, collection

Tenho um TreeSet que irá armazenar diversos objetos de uma classe "Produtos", essa classe possui 3 atributos:

> **int** codProduto;
> **String** descProduto;
> **float** precoProduto;

Após armazenar alguns objetos "Produto" nesse TreeSet, preciso imprimir o conteúdo de cada um deles. Para isso, fiz esse método:

```
public String imprimeLista(){
    Iterator<Produto> i = lProdutos.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(i.next() + " ");
    }
    return("");
}
```

Cadastrei 2 produtos para testar, e o que ele imprime é:

> proj.catalogo.Produto@28d93b30
>
> proj.catalogo.Produto@1b6d3586

Como eu posso fazer pra que ele imprima codProduto, descProduto e precoProduto?

Comment: Além disto não use `float` para valor monetário: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101. Deveria usar um `for ( : )` em vez de escrever o *loop* na mão. O erro é porque não pode imprimir o objeto, tem que fazer um método para fazer isto por voê ou criar um algoritmo de impressão dos membros individuais. Não use o `toString()` quase todo mundo usa mas ele não foi feito para imprimir coisas, é um método de depuração e retorno de um dado simples e com identidade facilmente reconhecível e *parseável*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você precisa implementar o método `toString()` da sua classe `Produto`. Veja um exemplo:

```
public class Produto {

    private int codProduto; 
    private String descProduto; 
    private float precoProduto;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Produto {" +
                "codProduto=" + codProduto +
                ", descProduto='" + descProduto + '\'' +
                ", precoProduto=" + precoProduto +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Exemplo de saída:

```
Produto{codProduto=123, descProduto='Descrição', precoProduto=123.0}
```

Este método `toString()` pode ser facilmente gerado pela sua IDE favorita.

Dica bônus: ao invés de usar `Float` para representar valores monetários, considere usar `BigDecimal`.